# Creating a split screen effect

Tags: freeware

I have two videos of the same length and I want to create one video with those 2 in a split screen manner.

I'm totally new to this field and I will probably never need to do this ever again so I'm looking for a quick and easy way that involves free software.

I tried VirtualDub but I'm lost in it's options and settings and I don't even know if it can do what I want to do.

EDIT: Context: each video is a recording of a PC screen. I want to show them in a split screen manner in order to display the way one PC influences the other. Audio is of no importance.

Comment: Do you want to show the full frame of both videos or only a portion?

Comment: I want to show the full frame of both

Comment: What about the audio of each?

Comment: Audio is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg, a command line tool, can accomplish this, via this command.

```
ffmpeg -i left -i right -lavfi [0:v][1:v]hstack -pix_fmt yuv420p -an combinedvideo.mp4
```

Replace `left` with filename of video to be positioned left. Same with `right`.

ffmpeg (32bit static build) can be downloaded from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). The ffmpeg.exe is in the `bin` folder of the archive.

Comment: This looks promising. I was able to make a quick test with it. Is there a recommended codec I should use? I tried to play the output .mp4 with Windows Media Player and it didn't work, but it played fine with ffplay. I should also resize the videos before doing this because the output was a bit huge (couldn't fit it on my screen in a mice way)

Comment: To resize the output, you can chain on a scale filter, like this: `-lavfi [0:v][1:v]hstack,scale=1920:-1` This will produce an output 1920 pixels wide and of proportional height so the video isn't stretched or squashed. The default codec, when one isn't specified explicitly, is H.264, so it's strange that WMP doesn't play it.

Comment: I think something it's missing from my PC. When the output isn't .mp4 WMP plays it with no problems. Thanks :)

Comment: If you have Quicktime installed, you can just change the final mp4 to mov